# Smart way to get unique index name from SqlException message?

Tags: sql-server, exception, ado.net, sqlexception, unique-index

Is there there any smart/best way to get the unique index name from `SqlException` message? like the following:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'partners.Partner' with
>   unique index 'IX_Partner_SerialId'. The statement has been terminated.

I need to get `IX_Partner_SerialId` without having to manipulate the exception message string? something like a variable in the exception object?

Comment: why can't you manipulate the string?

Comment: I can manipulate the string but I'm sure there could be a smart way like a dictionary stores these variables so we can use it? if there aren't any alternatives so this will be the only way.

Comment: I don't think SQL outputs exceptions with that much detail - it's in the message and that's probably all you will get.  It would be nice if it passed an URN or something for what caused the error, but there are too many possibilities to have that modeled effectively.

Comment: You can see all the info about the exceptions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.

You will have to parse message text. 
You can find the message texts and error numbers by querying

`SELECT * FROM SYSMESSAGES`